# count function isn't working as expected in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `a` with column `sdate` which is `TIMESTAMP`

I wanted to count the number of rows which `sdate` is empty.

when I'm doing

```
SELECT sdate
FROM a
WHERE sdate IS NULL
```

I get `13` rows.

So what I did after that was:

```
SELECT count(sdate) 
FROM a
WHERE sdate IS NULL
```

i expected to get `13` but i got `0`.
and I don't understand why.

When I changed it to:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM a
WHERE sdate IS NULL
```

I got `13` which the correct result.

Can someone explain why `SELECT count(sdate)` approach return false result?

Comment: `count(sdate)` but _sdate_ is always `null` (by your where-clause) and this is not counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 0 results when counting with below query:

```
SELECT count(sdate)
FROM a
WHERE sdate IS NULL
```

because `COUNT()` does not take in consideration NULL values. `COUNT()` only takes in consideration non-NULL values.

As opposed to when using:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM a
WHERE sdate IS NULL
```

which counts the number of rows in the entire table (because you're using `*`).

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60cd1/4) with the results returned by both `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: In addition, `count(*)` would also not count to the row count if all fields on the row were null. For these reasons I got into the habit of using `count(1)` a long time ago.

Comment: so i should always use count on PK?

Comment: @user223688 Either use count on PK or count(*). Or better yet, use Jor Egerton's approach.

Comment: You can count any non-null value - `count(1)` should be fine and universal.

Comment: Where can I read about these side effects of aggregation functions?

Comment: @JonEgerton: that's simply wrong. `*` _never_ evaluates to `null` and `count(*)` _will_ include rows where all columns are null: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/72e7f/1 There is absolutely ***no*** difference between `count(*)` and `count(1)` neither in functionality nor in performance.

Comment: @user223688: the manual is a good place to start: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html "*number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null*"

Comment: @user223688: also: this isn't specific to Postgres. This is how aggregates in the SQL standard are defined.

Comment: It's not a _side effect_ though, it's perfectly logical and functional (I'm not saying it's obvious). `NULL` is nothing, the absence of something, and it should not be counted. _Nothing + Nothing_ is still _Nothing_ :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: omg - you're spot on - just got back as far as the standards.Have been doing that a very long time though - wonder whether it was different on an old version of some RDBMS at some point maybe?

Comment: @JonEgerton: no, there never was a difference between `count(*)` and `count(1)` that is just a myth - a popular myth but still a myth.

Comment: I think it's easy to prove if there is absolute no difference between count(*) and count(1) then one of them is alias to the other meaning that at some point both should get to exactly the same code in the same library.

Comment: @user223688 actually mysql does exactly that: on parsing step the `COUNT(*)` token is replaced with `COUNT(1)`

Comment: @Mackan it is a side effect. there is a diffrence between counting nothing and counthing something that contains nothing. You can see it in GROUP THEORY. {} this array contains nothing... but  {{},{},{}} this array contains 3 arrays of nothing. it's not the same thing. Now assume that array is equivalent to row. Count is counting rows not what's inside the rows... At leaset that was my logic initially.

Comment: @user223688 Exactly, counting something that contains nothing. When you specify a column in the `count` it will count the values, and if the value is `null` it will not be counted. Using your array example that would be the same as counting values of the empty arrays. To count the actual rows `*` is used. I don't consider it a side effect by any stretch, as counting actual values is a nice function. But in the end it doesn't matter much what we call it. Per definition: _The COUNT(column_name) function returns the number of **values** (NULL values will not be counted) of the specified column_

Comment: @user223688: it's not a "side effect". This is how aggregates are defined in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

The [COUNT aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) takes an expression and it counts only rows for which such is *not* NULL. For example;

`COUNT(*)` - or `COUNT(1)`, eg. - counts every row.

`COUNT(col)` counts only the rows in which `col` is *not* NULL.

`COUNT(NULL)` - always zero.

In this case since the sdate columns for the selected rows (all) have null values those rows are *not* counted in `COUNT(sdate)` which results in a *correct* count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(null);
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)

Time: 1.772 ms
```

why surprised?..

[from:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html)

> The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known
>   whether two unknown values are equal.) This behavior conforms to the
>   SQL standard.

[count() reference:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

> count(expression) any bigint  number of input rows for which the value
>   of expression is not null

Comment: `COUNT` is counting rows. I had 13 rows of null. I didn't try to count something that doesn't exists. If that is what you think than you did not understand the question. Knowing that `COUNT` avoids these rows isn't that obvious as you claim.